# Converting nested JSON content dump to XLS

Tags: python, json, excel

I have a JSON dump from a content management site which follows the format:

```
[
    {
        id: "obj1",
        children: [...]
    },

    {
        id: "obj2",
        children: [...]
    }

]
```

There are 2-4 nesting levels.

What would be the best way to convert this to Microsoft Excel XLS so that nested levels are handled somehow, for the Excel-able customer to play with their data?

With this particular data, one way to do this would create a new sheet for each top level folder (nesting level). All sheets would contain the same column names picked from the JSON objects in that particular folder.

Are there any ready-made tools for importing JSON to Excel?

Preferably as a command-line tool and if scripting is required then in Python.

Comment: *“the best way to convert this”* – As we don’t know what your data exactly looks like, and more importantly what it contains, it’s hard for us to determine the best way to display your data in Excel. So, how would **you** display the data in Excel, without thinking of the underlying JSON data for a moment? If you can represent the data in some good way in Excel, then there surely is a way to convert the data to fit into that format.

Comment: I am more looking for tools which have ability to split tree like data to Excel columns.

Comment: There are tools that can do *anything* that Excel supports; hence my question: How do you want to represent the data?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your data.

If the nesting happens without any kind of repetition then simplest option is to replicate everything or leave blank spaces if your data is complete enough to be able to assume a repetition where you find a blank.

This means the XLS as a CSV will look like this:

```
Element1 Element1.1 Element1.1.1 ...
Element1 Element1.1 Element1.1.2 ...
Element2 Element2.1 Element2.1.1 ...
```

Where each element is a child of the one at its left. You can see a parent repeats as many times as children it has multiplied by how many times does each of the children appear.

You can also do a very simple table with two columns:

```
**Parent**    **Child**
Element1      Element1.1
Element1.1    Element1.1.1  
Element1.1    Element1.1.2
Element2      Element2.1
Element2.1    Element2.1.1
...
```

What an element is depends on your granularity. You can group pairs of key=values as a string, you can group several fields into one and parse it back with regular expressions, or you can separate everything and consider the key as an element and the value as another one.

Finally, if there is some regularity then you can take a more interesting approach, assume you have some repeating fieldnames, in that case you can take any of the previous approaches but using the fieldnames to generate a matrix instead of a list. The first example is trivial since it is obviously a tuple list that does already have an implicit ordinal header, the second one is a table and may look like a matrix already, but you can do this.

```
**Parent**    **Child (default)** **Repeating key1** **Repeating key2**
e1            e1.1
e1.1          e1.1.1
e.1.1.1                           something          
e.1.1         e.1.1.2
e.1.1.2                                               somethingelse
```

So basically in the end you have a sparse matrix.

There are very interesting ways to store matrixes with three dimensions using several sheets on an XLS, but human-readability may drop with it. It boils down to the data you are using, **there is no general solution**.

Comment: I would personally use the first option, with one row per deepest-level item and all parent information populated, leaving no blanks.  I believe this is the easiest to work with in Excel.  If two pieces of data are siblings, I would treat them as if one were a parent of the other.  Of course, this whole thing only works if each level of nesting means the same thing (can be assigned the same column) across all the data.  Otherwise, there really isn't *any* decent Excel solution, probably.

Answer (score 1):

I think **PHP - Spreadsheet engine**  is what you need..

here are some links for your query:

- [link 1](http://faisalman.github.com/simple-excel-php/)
- [link 2](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/)

hope this will help you ..:)

I guess you are asking for this..

```
            $excel = new SimpleExcel('csv');                    // instantiate new object (will automatically construct the parser & writer type as CSV)

           $excel->writer->setData(
               $array // this is array generated from json
            );                                                  // add some data to the writer
            $excel->writer->setDelimiter(";");                  // (optional) if delimiter not set, by default comma (",") will be used instead
            $excel->writer->saveFile('example');
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I do not see how it addresses the nesting problem.

Comment: @poke The answer was written before I added Python disclaimer

Answer (score 1):

Just use [flat library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flat) to flatten your object.

```
var flatten = require('flat')
 
flatten({
    key1: {
        keyA: 'valueI'
    },
    key2: {
        keyB: 'valueII'
    },
    key3: { a: { b: { c: 2 } } }
})
```

Output

```
{
  'key1.keyA': 'valueI',
  'key2.keyB': 'valueII',
  'key3.a.b.c': 2
}
```